# Not able to click on Google recaptcha checkbox (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

I have a python code that works for me, unfortunately it does not work on wix.com login page. (to see that page, open wix.com, click Sign In button, and then click Log in link to open the page)
The problem is with clicking on recaptcha box.
[This is a part of the relevant page html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNQug.png)

Here's the part of the code that I am using for testing:

`frames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA']") driver.switch_to.frame(frames) try: a = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "recaptcha-checkbox-border") a.click()`

Program goes in to the try area and then throws an error when trying to find the element.

I would appreciate if someone could help me find the reason why?
My guess it is something related to the page I am accessing as the same code works well on a different site.

Comment: Selenium is the kind of robot that CAPTCHA is supposed to prevent -.-

Comment: Perhaps so, but there is nothing sinister about automating your own work. I have been doing that for over 40 years. That is what computers and programmers are for. My question is specific and requires specific answer to a specific problem. Please help if you have the knowledge.

Comment: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-handle-captcha-in-selenium

Comment: Thank you for the link, unfortunately it doesn't improve my result, programs still  stops when trying to click on the recaptcha checkbox on this particular site I am using.